# Keras: test, cross validation and accuracy while processing batched data with train_on_batch

Tags: deep-learning, keras, batch-processing, metrics

Can someone point me to a *complete* example that does all of the following?

- Fits batched (and pickled) data in a loop using `train_on_batch()`
- Sets aside data from each batch for validation purposes
- Sets aside test data for accuracy evaluation after *all* batches have been processed (see last line of my example below).

I'm finding lots of 1 - 5 line code snippets on the internet illustrating how to call `train_on_batch()` or `fit_generator()`, but so far nothing that clearly illustrates how to separate out and handle both validation and test data while using `train_on_batch()`.

F. Chollet's great example Cifar10_cnn  (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) does not illustrate all of the points I listed above.

You can say, "Hey handling test data is your problem. Do it manually." Fine! But I don't understand what these routines do well enough to even know if that is necessary. They are mostly black boxes, and for all I know, they handle validation & test data automagically under the hood. My hope is that more complete example would clear up the confusion.

For instance, in the example below where I read batches iteratively from pickle files, how would I modify the call to `train_on_batch` to handle `validation_data`? And how do I set aside test data (`test_x` & `test_y`) for purposes of evaluating accuracy at the end of the algorithm?

```py
while 1:
    try:
        batch = np.array(pickle.load(fvecs))
        polarities = np.array(pickle.load(fpols)) 

        # Divide a batch of 1000 documents (movie reviews) into:
        # 800 rows of training data, and
        # 200 rows of test (validation?) data
        train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(batch, polarities, test_size=0.2)

        doc_size = 30
        x_batch = pad_sequences(train_x, maxlen=doc_size)
        y_batch = train_y

        # Fit the model 
        model.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
        # model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), epochs=2, batch_size=800, verbose=2)

    except EOFError:
        print("EOF detected.")
        break

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't supply you with a complete example but as you can see [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-keras-with-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory) you have both train_on_batch as well as test_on_batch which should suggest that the "train_on_batch" function should only **train** the model and not test it.

Just to be extra sure you can see in the code [itself](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py) that the function uses the entire batch for training and nothing is used to test/validate.

For your convenience I'm quoting the relevant code below:

```py
def train_on_batch(self, x, y,
                   sample_weight=None,
                   class_weight=None):
    """Runs a single gradient update on a single batch of data.
    # Arguments
        x: Numpy array of training data,
            or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple inputs.
            If all inputs in the model are named,
            you can also pass a dictionary
            mapping input names to Numpy arrays.
        y: Numpy array of target data,
            or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple outputs.
            If all outputs in the model are named,
            you can also pass a dictionary
            mapping output names to Numpy arrays.
        sample_weight: Optional array of the same length as x, containing
            weights to apply to the model's loss for each sample.
            In the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array
            with shape (samples, sequence_length),
            to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample.
            In this case you should make sure to specify
            sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().
        class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping
            class indices (integers) to
            a weight (float) to apply to the model's loss for the samples
            from this class during training.
            This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to
            samples from an under-represented class.
    # Returns
        Scalar training loss
        (if the model has a single output and no metrics)
        or list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs
        and/or metrics). The attribute `model.metrics_names` will give you
        the display labels for the scalar outputs.
    """
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_user_data(
        x, y,
        sample_weight=sample_weight,
        class_weight=class_weight,
        check_batch_axis=True)
    if self.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int):
        ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.]
    else:
        ins = x + y + sample_weights
    self._make_train_function()
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
    if len(outputs) == 1:
        return outputs[0]
    return outputs
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. What you say about `test_on_batch` makes sense. How about (cross) validation? That is normally done separately from both training and testing. Also, how can you do meaningful testing of accuracy at the batch level? It makes no sense to test the accuracy of a model that is, say, half-trained, since the entire purpose of an accuracy metric is to determine if the training worked. How, in other words, do you implement an accuracy metric in an algorithm that is reading in data little by little from a huge dataset?

Comment: Usually you would want to keep track of your test accuracy to check for over/under-fitting and other related problems. doing so mid-epoch is certainly weird and you would usually do this at the end of each epoch - then you could use test_on_batch if your test set is also huge. On some occasions (if your epochs are very long, certain GAN algorithms or other edge cases) you might want to test your model mid-epoch but I don't remember ever seeing it done.

Comment: @ginge can you explain how we could test accuracy at the end of each epoch using test_on_batch when the validation set is also huge? In other words, how do you implement an accuracy metric using mini batches?